# conditional blocks in haml

Tags: ruby, haml, erb

in ruby you can do conditional block like so

```
block do |n|
  puts n
end if foo == bar
```

which would translate into erb as

```
<% block do |n| %>
  <%= n %>
<% end if foo == bar %>
```

is there a way to achieve this in haml other than wrapping the block in a condition?

Comment: You could do that in Ruby, but you would be using, in my opinion, and in the opinion of many others, bad style: see [GitHub's Ruby style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) which says to avoid do end chaining.

Comment: Even if I was to say "ok, the `do` ... `end.if` style is readable" (it is not), I cringe to see it done in Haml. I'll give some alternatives in the answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- block do |n|
  = n
- end if foo == bar
```

Haml does allow `end` in this circumstance.

Comment: You simultaneously answered the question and made my eyes bleed. Please, for the love of Haml, don't encourage this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please put the `if` up front -- it makes it more readable:

```
- if foo == bar
  - block do |n|
    = n
```

And, if this occurs frequently, consider writing a custom Haml helper.

(I mentioned the [GitHub Ruby Style guide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) above in a comment. If you [search Google for 'ruby do end chaining'](http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+do+end+chaining) you'll see many style guides that recommend using that construct.)